# open .chm file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, chm, html-help-workshop

I'm using below code to open help file in `asp.net`

```
protected void lblHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath(@"VersionControlHelp.chm");    
    Process.Start(filepath);
}
```

this works perfectly in my local machine but not working when i published to the `IIS` server. are there any `IIS` settings that i should modify?

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working - what error did you get? Also, where is the .chm located?

Comment: If something like that is working locally but failing live, probably there must be some path / address issue   check where is the file physically  located on server..

Comment: Not working means the file is not opening.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `Process.Start()` on the web server, you will get the CHM file opening on the server, in the context of the IIS application pool user, which has no console attached (so nothing will happen).

I'm certain this is not what you want.

I think you are attempting to open the CHM file on the client machine. To do this, call `Response.Redirect("pathto/yourchmfile.chm")` from within your `lblHelp_Click` method. That will cause the browser to download the CHM file, and the user will then have the option of opening it (subject to browser warnings) or saving it. I think that's about as close as you'll get.

(By the way, it works locally because the ASP.NET development server bundled with Visual Studio is just a system tray application, loaded at user login - so if this issues a `Process.Start()`, the CHM file will be opened in the context of the user running Visual Studio, i.e. you, attached to a console session, i.e. your screen.)

Answer (score 0):

If this already worked locally, then it might be because of permission or incorrect path. If you are catching the exception silently, you may not see the error e.g. Access denied, Path not found

If the file is in the root of your web application, you can try this

```
protected void lblHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/VersionControlHelp.chm");    
    Process.Start(filepath);
}
```

Also, the `@` is symbol is not needed since you were not using backslash (`\`) or any special character

Answer (score 0):

the Process.Start may need enough previlege to run. so you need to check the current application pool identity of your website, is this have enought previlege to start a process on the server?